# Create a menu with the bootstrap site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a menu like this : http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
I try many class and styles but No response I got.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, just add the [bootstrap css](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css), [bootstrap.js](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com)(before `bootstrap.js`) and use classes defined in that `css` file and it's completely documentated in the site itself you are referring to. [Just an example here :](http://jsfiddle.net/4NpzP/1/)

```
    <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
      <a href="../" class="navbar-brand">My Menu</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Page One</a>
           </li>
           <li>
              <a href="#">Page Two</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="#">Page Three</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Download these files mentioned above (or use from cdn) and keep the `css` file in your head tag

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

and following `js` files before the closing body tag to, like

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

For a clear understanding, check this [basic template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) section.

Comment: I meant the left menu not the upper menu. i want to implemet that sticky menu that show active section.

Comment: @EhsanSadeghi, where did you mentioned about the sidebar menu, I didn't see it anywhere in your question.

Comment: Ok, Please guide me how to create that?